# issue with Authorize.net api call started returning null

Tags: php, laravel, sdk, authorize.net

A very strange thing happened.  Our app stopped connecting to auth.net.  We had made no code changes.  At some point last night the transactions stopped.  We have been trying to figure out why.  THis is what we have.

The API call is supposed to always return something liken en error but it is returning NULL.  We have run a ton of test and still have issues

```
 $ch = curl_init('https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

this returns the following

> - Trying 198.241.207.86...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Connected to apitest.authorize.net (198.241.207.86) port 443 (#0)
> - ALPN, offering http/1.1
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
> - SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> - ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: C=US; ST=Georgia; L=Suwanee; O=MIS Solutions, Inc.; OU=Cloud; CN=*.greenlightcloud.net
> - start date: Jun  8 00:00:00 2020 GMT
> - expire date: Jul  8 12:00:00 2022 GMT
> - subjectAltName does not match apitest.authorize.net
> - SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'apitest.authorize.net'
> - stopped the pause stream!
> - Closing connection 0

We reinstalled the sdk via composer.  We also updated the SSL cert manually from git and no change.

We tried the sample code from git and we get the "Charge Credit Card Null response returned" which means the call is returning null.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I think your curl function is failed to access ssl based api test, if you see result, there is clearly mentioned subjectAltName not matching, also check htaccess anything in cases added which is blocking api

Comment: no .htaccess file.  I can see that the subjectAltName not matching but have no idea what the means or how to resolve it.  Nothing comes up on google or the 100 other searches I have done..

Answer (score 1):

Check your firewall.  We found that the IP for Authorize.net went from a server in US to Singapore overnight and is now blocked on our firewall.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, that ended up being it.  Pretty lame of Authorize.net to do that and not notify its users.  Why the hell would they move the servers to Singapore for US users anyway?

Comment: We are told by our network provider that the auth.net did not relocate their server to Singapore but that it was a GEOIP location error.  Seems suspicious to me that out of the blue  GEOIP made an error for one. of the largest credit card processors IP location.